# Xamarin.Android: System.Runtime.Caching can not resolve reference

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a solution with:

1. A project that handles business logic through crud functions. At some point the project uses `System.Runtime.Caching`
2. Other webforms, MVC and RESTservice projects. (irrelevant to the topic)
3. A newly created Xamarins.Forms project targeting `.netstandard2.0`

My problem is that when I reference the business logic project in the Xamarin.forms project then the Xamarin.Android project errors that it can not resolve the reference System.Runtime.Caching referenced by the business logic project. 
It suggests that I add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Runtime.Caching`, or remove the reference to the business logic project.

I have tried installing the package for both the Xamarin.Forms project and the related Xamarin.Android project. But it does nothing.

I am in a bit of halt here since I am unable to figure what the problem is and better yet how to sovle it.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Runtime.Caching` doesnt seem [to be part of .Net standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.0) hence you can not add it .Check the nuget log when you try to add it.

You might be calling web project/API project code directly from xamarin forms, dont do that. You need to isolate the two.